# session_submit() in tidyverse in R error: "all components of query must be named"

Tags: r, web-scraping, tidyverse, rvest

I'm trying to log into a website using the html session from the tidyverse in R. I can't make it totally reproducible because I don't want to paste my login credentials out in the world. Worst case scenario I could maybe change my password and do it and change it back. Anyways, here goes:
I have a script that scrapes a website. It used to work last year when I ran it, but this year, when I try to login, I have an error thrown on the line that tries to login. Here is the code scrubbed of sensitive info

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(textutils)

session <- html_session(website)
loginForm <- html_form(session)[[1]] # First (and only) form
loginFormFilled <- set_values(loginForm, username = "myname", password = "mypassword")

session_submit(x = session, form = loginFormFilled)
```

> Error: All components of query must be named

When I look at the form, it looks reasonably filled out:
[image]
When I googled it, I found absolutely nothing for the error in this context, only in some seemingly different contexts. I know I don't have it fully reproducible because I'm trying to protect my info, but anyone have any idea what this might mean with the given detail?

Answer (score 2):

This is a very frustrating problem that I've faced several times before. Notice that your `username`, `password`, and `remember` form fields have a name and a value separated by a colon. But the button has no name, just the value of `Login`.

In my case, I was able to resolve the "all components of query must be named" issue by assigning a name to the unnamed button:

```
 loginFormFilled$fields[[4]]$name <- "button"
```

The form then goes from:

```
<field> (submit) : Login
```

to:

```
  <field> (submit) button: Login
```

And since it's now named, the submission succeeds.